# Polymorphism Design

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I am trying to decide whether or not to use polymorphism for my problem. Below is a dummy problem similar to my problem I created for the sake of this question:

Let's say I have a base class Shape with derived classes Rectangle, Triangle, and Circle. All of them have an Area() function implemented. I have n vectors of Shapes; `vector<Shape*> v_1, v_2, v_3, ..., v_n`. The output I want is `vector<Rectangle*> maxrec`, which stores the Shape of the maximum area in each `v_1, v_2, ..., v_n` only if it's a Rectangle. (For example, if the maximal area Shape in `v_i` is a Rectangle, I add it to maxrec. If not, I don't.)

Since the input is `vector<Shape*>`, is it acceptable to cast a `Shape*` element to a `Rectangle*` element before adding it to `maxrec`? Or is there a design flaw that I'm missing here? Is polymorphism appropriate? (I don't have a problem with the algorithmic part, just the polymorphism design part.)

Answer (score 0):

What you have to think about is are the "Shapes" actually going to share any functions or fields. For example, they will all have area (even if calculated in different ways), however I don't think that is necessarily enough to justify a parent class. I think it's important for us to know what the role of these shapes will be to justify using polymorphism or not.

Answer (score 0):

It is not acceptable to cast any Shape* to Rectangle*. You would need to use the `dynamic_cast` operator. For example:

```
Shape *shape=...;
Rectangle *rec=dynamic_cast<Rectangle*>(shape);
```

If shape truly is a Rectangle, you will have a valid pointer to a Rectangle in rec, otherwise rec will be NULL.

Comment: Someone correct me if I am wrong but I think his question is more stylistic than programming specifics